# In code for ESP32, In enum error Not initialized input data pointer

Tags: c++, enums, esp32

I write code for led driver IS31FL3236A for **esp32 in IDF**. And I was wondering how describe registers.
I found some tip on this [site](https://accu.org/journals/overload/13/68/goodliffe_281). This solution apart from elegant should be also  guarantee efficiency.

This solution allow me hiden raw number registers, and usage is more readable. But I get error **Not initialized input data pointer**.

Below in shortly how looks definitions and usage.

```
***********************Registers.h file********************************
enum Registers
{
    RESET = 0x4F,
};

inline uint8_t *RegAdd(Registers reg)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(reg);
}

enum RegistersVal
{
    DEFAULT = 0x00,
};

inline uint8_t *RegVal(RegistersVal val)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(val);
}

***********************Driver source file****************************

esp_err_t err = Write(RegAdd(RESET), RegVal(DEFAULT)); //usage and line with error


esp_err_t LEDDriver::Write(uint8_t *registerAdd, uint8_t *registerVal)
{
    return i2c_bus_write_bytes(i2c_bus, 0x3C << 1, registerAdd, 1, registerVal, 1);;
}



E (1311) I2C_BUS: ..../driver/i2c_bus/i2c_bus.c:92 (i2c_bus_write_bytes):Not initialized input data pointer
ESP_ERROR_CHECK failed: esp_err_t 0xffffffff (ESP_FAIL) at 0x40380d0c
0x40380d0c: _esp_error_check_failed at ..../esp/esp-idf/components/esp_system/esp_err.c:42
```

Comment: The pointer with data, which you pass to `Write()` is NULL. You want to give it a pointer that points to a `uint8_t` with a zero (`DEFAULT`) value.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt You mean `nullptr` (i.o. NULL) right?

Comment: It assing value val to pointer as addres in memory not value of variable val. So we have a uint8_t* p = 0x00, and not uint8_t v = 0x00 and next uint8_t* p1 = &v